# MMULT / MINVERSE Maximum array size

Tags: excel, math, matrix

I am attempting to solve this set of equations:

```
696x +  405y +  61z    = 1385699
618x +  463y +  81z    = 1401476
573x +  476y +  113z   = 1407438
508x +  537y +  117z   = 1418256
473x +  566y +  123z   = 1427224
```

x,y and z are removed in the worksheet.

Using the following formula: `E2:E5 {=MMULT(MINVERSE("A1:C5"),"D1:D5")}`

But I keep encountering value errors.

Can MINVERSE only be used with a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: No, but it can only be used on **square** matrices: ["MINVERSE also returns the #VALUE! error value if array does not have an equal number of rows and columns."](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/minverse-HP005209179.aspx)

Comment: You have five equations in three variables so your problem is [overdetermined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system) - you should decide what you want to do about that.

Comment: +1 (+1!) In this kind of scenario how does one determine which 3 of 5 equations are best to use? I am about to test to see the differences.

Comment: What is the accuracy of say producing coefficients from each combination and then taking a mean of each result?

Comment: Sorry, I only know enough to know that there's a problem... these two qs on [math.se] look promising though: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46036/solving-an-overdetermined-system-of-nonlinear-equations http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/check-whether-an-overdetermined-linear-equation-system-is-consistent-general-ap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your system of equations is overdetermined you may instead be looking to find the  *pseudoinverse* or least squares estimate. To calculate this, select a 1 x 3 range such as F1:H1 then enter the array formula:

```
=LINEST(D1:D5,A1:C5,0)
```

entered by holding down CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. For the given example, this returns {z,y,x} = {1191.8,1345.3,1103.7}. Note that the results coincide with MINVERSE for square matrices.

Comment: Great! It's been too long since I've had to use matrices almost forgotten everything!